# Creating a win streak function in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a cell that can track win streak/losing streaks for my sheet

Basically

Overall Stats B9 Cell: gathers data of Trades sheet Z column of positive and negative R(return) and if there are multiple positive Rs, it would count the winning streak. If you could also create a losing streak that would help thank you.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OQg3R0796dRjlHZb4wZzaTM2QgjIRuICOroq8e5xXi8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Fiverr or Craigslist may be better sites for getting people to do work for you.

Comment: By sharing spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). Instead, use [tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/). You can easily create a table using the formula: `=ARRAYFORMULA("|"&A1:G20)`, if you want to share `A1:G20`. However, the first row `A1:G1` must be a header row AND the second row `A2:G2` should only contain dashes `--` in all the cells.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take this opportunity to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13196995/daniel-h)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(Z:Z, Z:Z*1>0)))
```

and:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(Z:Z, Z:Z*1<0)))
```